# Tracking Attendees with Calendar Events

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, events

We are using SharePoint Events for training but we have no idea who is registering. Below is an example of a stat holiday. If the user clicks 'Add to my calendar', it creates an individual .ics

Is there a way to send out a shared calendar invite instead of individual .ics files so we can track who is registering for these events?

[image]

Comment: Note using a regular "Events" list, no.  If you are using a "group-connected" site, you can use the outlook-connected Group calendar and the [Group Calendar WebPart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce)

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online, the best approach for your goal may still be using the [Group calendar in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/schedule-a-meeting-on-a-group-calendar-in-outlook-0cf1ad68-1034-4306-b367-d75e9818376a#Outlook=Web) to arrange and use the group calendar web part mentioned by willman. It is more integrated with office 365 group for you to track and manage group member events.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work for tracking who accepted the event. When they click 'Add to my Calendar', it provides a single .ics file which creates a separate event in their calendar. They are not added to the original Calendar invite and the admin has no idea who is attending their training event.

Comment: have you found any solution yet?

Comment: No Solution yet @LucAna :(